# Android - service doesn't start on boot

Tags: java, android

Following my code:

Into manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Into application:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.Onstart">  <!-- Tested also only .Onstart -->
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Onstart.java:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Onstart extends BroadcastReceiver {    

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
            context.startService(new Intent(context, Myservice.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Myservice.java:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Myservice extends IntentService
{

    public Myservice() {
        super("Myservice");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        int n=0;
        while(true)
        {
            Log.i("Test", "n."+n++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            { }
        }
    }

}
```

I can't see on LogCat any log on start, so I presume that the service doesn't start at boot. Why it doesn't work? How to solve it?

Comment: 1. Is your app installed on SD card? 2. Are you making sure your app is launced at least one time using a MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity`?

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED has been known to act weird, and can even be device dependent. For example, HTC has another broadcast (I think QUICK_BOOT) that it calls on restarts instead of BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: @zgc7009 how to solve it?

Comment: @Bob : OK, an app installed on SD card can't listen for `BOOT_COMPLETED` because that `Intent` is broadcast immediately boot completes but is before the SD card is mounted. That's why it's failing. Move your app to internal memory and try again.

Comment: did u try to print anything onCreate method of ur service?

Comment: @Squonk I tested it just now without sd card, same...

Comment: @eldjon putting System.out.println("test"); after if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")), it works! But service doens't print nothing on LogCat, so only service doesn't start...

Comment: @zgc7009 catch (InterruptedException e){ System.out.println("catch"); } doens't print nothing...

Comment: Yea sorry, realized you were printing a increment log after I suggested that.

Comment: @zgc7009 I also tried to print a log in the first line of onHandleIntent, and it doens't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You registered your service in your manifest?

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks you a lot, I did not know that you need to do it.